# Is there a way to control ringer volume with siri?

Tags: ios, siri

I can't get siri to change the ringer volume. When I ask "increase the ringer volume" (or anything similar) I get the answer "You don't seem to be playing anything at the moment".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siri can't change the phone's ringer volume.

[Here's a good list](https://techranker.net/siri-commands-list-how-to-use/) of commands you can use with Siri.